# Bat file output into one long string

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Is there anyway to have the output from this bat file into one long string e.g.

11/03/2015, 9:36:24.28, Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 0, Lost = 1 (100% loss), Minimum = 170ms, Maximum = 170ms, Average = 170ms

```
@ECHO off
set IPADDRESS=192.168.4.1
set INTERVAL=60
:PINGINTERVAL
echo %date% %time% >>CFConnection.txt
ping %IPADDRESS% -n 1 | FIND "loss" >>CFConnection.txt
ping %IPADDRESS% -n 1 | FIND "Minimum" >>CFConnection.txt
timeout %INTERVAL%
GOTO PINGINTERVAL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `set /P "=output"<NUL` to write text to CFConnection.txt without a line break.

```js
set /P "=output"<NUL
```

does pretty much the same thing as

```js
echo output
```

but without a carriage return at the end.

You should also use `findstr` so you can match lines containing "loss" or "minimum" with one command, and so you're not trying to mash two ping results together into one dubious log entry of deceit and treachery.  And finally, any time you want to capture the output of a command, use a `for /f` loop.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

set "IP=192.168.4.1"
set "interval=60"

:loop
>>CFConnection.txt (
    (
        set /P "=%date% %time%, "<NUL
        for /f "delims=" %%I in ('ping -n 1 %IP% ^| findstr /i "loss minimum"') do (
            set /P "=%%I "<NUL
        )
        echo;
    )
)
timeout %interval%
goto loop
```

Comment: Thanks very much rojo, whereas the best place to learn this stuff?

Comment: The best way to learn how to do something is to teach others how to do it.  :)  If my answer above was the solution to all your problems, please mark it as accepted.